# How to resize SQL limit during querying

Tags: php, sql, limit

I am querying a MySQL database for some records by the query which limit result max records to 4, but i want add to this result all records which has "keep_actual" column set on 1 but excludes all previous founded records. What is the best way to do this?

```
  // Sample query which return those 4 i need
  // Result should be those 4 + all from current $cat which has keep_actual=1 but not are in those first 4
 $news = $ed->getByLanguage($lang_id, null, false, 4,false,true);

public function getByLanguage($lang, $cat=null, $main=true, $limit=null, $hasImage=false, $isTopped=false) {

        if ($cat == null) {
            $where = "language_id=$lang";
        } else {
            $where = "language_id=$lang and category_id=$cat";
        }
        if ($main == false && $isTopped==false) {
            $where.=" and main=0";
        }
        if ($hasImage == true) {
            $where.=" and main_picture is not null";
        } 

       if($cat==12){
        $limit=10;
       }

        //Nastavuje, zda se ma zobrazovat top nebo ne(na uvodni strane a aktualne)
        if($isTopped==true)
            $where.=" and top = 1";
        //=========================================================

        //$where.=" and entry.date >= '".date("Y-m-d h:i:s", mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, date("Y")))."' and entry.date <= '".date("Y-m-d h:i:s")."'";
        if ($limit == 1) {
            //nahledy
          return parent::selectOne($this->sc->select("entry", "main_picture,url,name,abstract,date,top", $where, null, "date", $limit));
        } else {
            //main clanek
            return parent::selectAll($this->sc->select("entry", "*", $where, null, "date", $limit));
        }
    }


public function selectAll($sql) {
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        if ($res) {
            $a = array();
            $i = 0;
            while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
//                print_r($r);
                foreach ($r as $k => $v) {
                    $a[$i][$k] = $v;
                }
                $i++;
            }

            return $a;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using 'NOT IN'? As in: WHERE ID NOT IN (ID1, ID2, ID3, ID4)? That way, you can specifically exclude particular IDs from your query result. Though I don't really see what you're trying to do here to be honest.

Comment: I have function which return first four articles, this works, now i have to add to this result records which are set as actual(contains keep_actual=1 but excludes all those in first four) so there will be no duplicate result in case when anyone from the first four got keep_actual = 1 too. So now limit is 4, and there is for example total 10 record which has keep_actual=1 but, there are 2 records in first 4 which has keep_actual=1, so they are already in result so i need i have to exclude them from those 10, so 4<now working>+10<all keep_actual=1>-2<have keep_actual=1 but are in first 4>=12rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is 'generic' code, you need to adapt it to your needs, but this is how it should work:

```
$res = mysqli_query($sql, "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `Condition` = 1 LIMIT 4");
$results = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) $results[] = $row;

$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `keep_actual` = 1 AND ID NOT IN (";
for($i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i) $query .= "$row[ID], ";
$query .= "0)"; //To terminate the list of IDs
$res = mysqli_query($sql, $Query);
```

This code SHOULD give you what you're looking for, but it's completely untested and rather abstract.

Comment: @MartinŠevic Glad to be of service.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to add a comment, so I will have to post this as answer.

Would be really useful if you could put some example data in the question, so that we can visualise what you are trying to do; just a few rows, and then highlight which ones you would expect to be selected for the query.